# While playing a sound does not stop recording Avcapture

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avcapture

I have a view where a video record, then I have a section AVAudioPlayer, the problem is that when the sound, you stop registazione Video.

```
testAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:sampleData error:&audioError];
[sampleData release];

if(audioError != nil) {
    NSLog(@"An audio error occurred: \"%@\"", audioError);
}
else {
    [testAudioPlayer setVolume:100];
    [testAudioPlayer setNumberOfLoops: -1];
    [testAudioPlayer play];``
```

thanks in advance

Comment: i search this from another post but i don't know where remove code please help me!!I figured it out: I just had to remove some code within AVCam that allocated AVCaptureDeviceInput - audioInput. That was unnecessary and conflicted with my audio playback code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution create AVaudiosession to viewdidload

```
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:     AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: &setCategoryError]; 

if (setCategoryError) { NSLog(@"%@",[setCategoryError description]); }

OSStatus propertySetError = 0;
UInt32 allowMixing = true;

propertySetError = AudioSessionSetProperty ( kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof (allowMixing), &allowMixing);
```