# Which way is more simple to capture Audio by mic, meanwhile play the audio? like audio amplifier

Tags: ios, core-audio, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I have roughly researched audio APIs for iOS. There are several layer APIs to perform audio capture and play.

My app needs a simple function like audio amplifier (needs delay around 0.2 Seconds). I don't need save record to file. I am not sure which way is more simple to implement it. Core Audio? Or AVfoundation?

[How do I record audio on iPhone with AVAudioRecorder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder) I am not sure does this link working with my case or not.

[While playing a sound does not stop recording Avcapture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279157/while-playing-a-sound-does-not-stop-recording-avcapture) This link is playing other audio when recording. It is not suit my case.

Answer (score 1):

For buffered near-simultaneous audio record and playback, you will need to use either the Audio Queue API or Audio Units such as RemoteIO.  Audio Units will allow a lower latency.